# Web Application for SEO Youtube Videos, err msg don't have permission to access the requested object

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, google-api, xampp

**Edit: I reinstalled Xampp and changed the httpd.conf file again and still same result for no reason**

I'm making a SEO youtube video website the process is put the link press the button and the website gonna analyze.
**First Phase** I want to get the title, description, views, like, etc.. then print these data

**the second phase** then API with Google trends to check if it's well formated and has good title and description then gives him the score out of 100 Also if someone could give me an advice about it or if there is a better process to do it (in terms of finding best SEO Keywords and API google trends)

I'm facing a trouble in embeding Youtube video url after clicking a button i got this error message i edited the httpd.conf, i added this in each `<Directory` and i still get this error message

```
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
```

and this my php code

```
$input_Url_data = '';
 /* store the link of the video in a variable */
$input_Url_data  = $_GET['url'] ; 

echo $input_Url_data  ;

echo '<span> <?php echo $input_Url_data ; ?></span>';
$id_position= ''; 
  /*  get the Video ID when the user click the button and make sure it's GET */
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" and isset($_GET['submit'])){
      /* triming the link to get the id */
      echo  "</br >" ; 
      echo   $input_Url_data   .  "Button clicked" ;      
      $id_position = strstr($input_Url_data,"=");
      $id_position = trim($id_position, "=" );
  /*  embed the the link by the id */
      echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo "https://www.youtube.com/embed". $id_position ; ?> "title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ;

}
```

this's the website from xampp localhost

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't xampp but after many articles I found a way for embeding Youtube Videos which is using backspace in attributes, I even don't know why but it's working

```
echo "<iframe  position=\"center\"allow=\"accelerometer\"; gyroscope;  width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$ytcode\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ?

```
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo "https://www.youtube.com/embed/". $id_position ; ?> "title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Same result, the problem is the server refusing to use any php variables in html, I made changes to httpd.conf file and same error message